# Schoasch, Schosef und Schakop

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

Mein Großvater, geboren 1897 in Straßburg, hat Josef geheißen.  Er war bekannt als *de' Sepp* oder *de' Seppel*. Dennoch hätte man Josef als Schosef ausgesprochen und nicht /jo:sɛf/. Einen alten Kollegen von mir aus Graz hab' ich immer mit *Schoasch* angeredet, obwohl er offiziell Georg heißt.  Im *Wörterbuch der elsässischen Mundarten* von Martin und Lienhart findet man *Schakop* als Stichwort mit folgendem Hinweis *s. Jakob*.

Wie verbreitet sind denn diese Formen, die der französischen Aussprache näher sind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Namen Jakob und Josef entstammen dem Hebräischen; der Anlaut ist der hebräische Buchstabe Jod. Sie wurden als *Iakobus* und *Iosephus* ins Lateinische (das damals kein J kannte). Von dort gelangten sie in viele europäische Sprachen, wobei das I durch J ersetzt wurde. In einigen, vor allem westlichen romanischen Sprachen wurde durch Lautwandel im Laufe der Zeit aus diesem /j/ ein /ʒ/ oder /dʒ/; im Deutschen und in vielen osteuropäischen Sprachen nicht. Da die Namen alt waren, entwickelten sich mit der Zeit verschiedene Kurzformen; insbesondere ist ein Josef in Bayern in der Regel ein Sepp, im Rheinland ein Jupp und so weiter. Französische Formen, die im Elsass oder in Lothringen vorkommen können, kommen im restlichen Deutschland für diese Namen *nicht* vor; das gilt insbesondere auch für Gegenden wie Rheinhessen, die sehr viel französischen Einfluss in ihrem Wortschatz haben (Auf Rheinhessisch sagt man anstatt *ich* zum Beispiel *sche* mit stimmhaftem sch).

Der Name Georg ist griechischen Ursprungs und auch über Latein zu uns gekommen; hat aber von Anfang an ein G als Anlaut gehabt. Dieser palatalisierte und lenisierte sprachgeschichtlich wohl schon sehr früh auf dem Weg vom Lateinischen ins Französische (und andere romanische Sprachen) – es wurde also aus dem /g/ ein /dʒ/. Das Deutsche hat hier wieder nicht mitgemacht, demnach sagen wir heutzutage in der Regel Georg mit zweimal /g/. Dennoch hat sich im gesamten süd- und westdeutschen Raum die Kurzform *Schorsch* für *Georg* angelehnt an die Französische Aussprache durchgesetzt (kurz, weil sie im Gegensatz zu *Ge-org* einsilbig ist) – und sie wird in ganz Deutschland verstanden. Wie alt diese Form ist, habe ich in meiner kurzen Recherche leider nicht herausfinden können.

Andere Namen auf G mit vorderem Vokal, wie *Gilbert*, werden auf Französisch zwar auch /ʒ/ ausgesprochen, es gibt aber meines Wissens keine Kurz- oder Nebenform *Schilbert* oder dergleichen. Manche, wie *Gernot*, sind gar germanischen Ursprungs und sollten gar nicht in den Verdacht einer romanisierten Form kommen.

Zusammengefasst: Schorsch als französische Variante von Georg wird im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum verstanden und im Süden und Westen desselben verwendet. Es ist eine Ausnahme: Andere Vornamen kennen keine solche Variante, auch wenn sie in Frankreich anders ausgesprochen werden.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort.  Ich würde nur hinzufügen, dass die gegenwärtige französische Aussprache von Gilbert und Georges mit /ʒ/ beginnt, also /ʒilbɛʀ/ und /ʒɔʀʒ/

Comment: @petitrien Stimmt, das d hätte weg gemusst ^^'

Comment: Dass *Schorsch* in ganz Deutschland verstanden wird verdannen wir spätestens der Figur aus der Sesamstraße. Dass *Schorsch* überall als Georg gedeutet wird kann ich so nicht bestätigen.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Ich bin in Graz geboren, und im Alter von 30 Jahren nach Wien übersiedelt, 20 Jahre später nach St. Pölten.</sub>

Die Varianten *Schosef* (für Josef) und *Schakop* (für Jakob) sind mir gänzlich unbekannt.

Für Georg ist im Osten Österreich die Variante **Schoasch** einigermaßen gängig. Wesentlich häufiger, aber nur in Wien und Umgebung, findet man **Schurl** oder **Schurli** für *Georg*. So wurde beispielsweise der leider schon verstorbene Austropop-Sänger [Georg Danzer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Danzer) von Kollegen und Wiener Fans immer *Schurli* genannt. Fans aus der Steiermark blieben eher bei *Georg* oder *da Danza* (»der Danzer«).

Answer (score 1):

"Schorsch" ist eine in Deutschland weit verbreitete Dialektform von Georg. Vgl. dazu https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg. Im Bayrischen wird das m.E. eher wie "Schoasch" ausgesprochen, im Hessischen ist das "r" meist kaum hörbar. In Hessen und den angrenzenden Regionen gibt es laut Google übrigens mehrere Gaststätten mit Namen "Zum Schorsch".

Answer (score 1):

Eine Suche mit Google zeigt, dass "Schakob" auch in Deutschland nicht völlig unbekannt ist. Die Verwendung dieser Dialektform scheint allerdings auf Regionen beschränkt zu sein, die ans Elsass angrenzen.

**Zeitungsartikel:**

https://www.bo.de/lokales/offenburg/mit-leib-und-seele-31-jahre-lang-busfahrer

*Neuried-Altenheim (df). Eine überaus große Trauergemeinde begleitete Jakob Mild, besser bekannt als »Schakob, der Busfahrer« auf seinem letzten irdischen Gang.*

https://www.badische-zeitung.de/neuried/ein-wiedersehen-mit-dem-schakob--70854474.html

*Als die Bauern noch Kühe und Pferde vor die Karren spannten, hatte der "Schakob", wie Jakob Bär auf Alemannisch gerufen wurde, alle Hände voll zu tun.*

https://www.lahrer-zeitung.de/inhalt.meissenheim-grosses-kino-in-meissenheim.83733ac4-672a-4a5a-911a-a36bf4d8868b.html

*Die Brüder Andres und Schakob Schäfer, verkörpert von Bernd Heimburger und René Wilhelm, führten sowohl auf der Leinwand als auch in der Halle durch den Jahreslauf.*

**Bücher:**

Reimereien des alten Grünrocks aus der Pfalz: Hochdeutsch und in heimischer Mundart

https://books.google.de/books?id=GXScDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=schakob&source=bl&ots=d_DJHVN9G_&sig=ACfU3U0W249el1FN2QTc-caIJsE38pxkKQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUmJ_o--jjAhUIKVAKHcSeDlw4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=schakob&f=false

*In de Rucksack vun dem Schakob*

*Do secht nun zum Fritz mein Schakob*

Der Amerika-Schakob. ein zielbewußter Mann macht keine Faxen - Roman aus dem Pfälzer Weinland

https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Georg-Wagner+Der-Amerika-Schakob-ein-zielbewu%C3%9Fter-Mann-macht-keine-Faxen-Roman-aus-dem-Pf%C3%A4lzer/id/A02l43zR01ZZX?zid=7k0h3clmhkfbdhfae2ke6ndho2

Bei uns in Sulz. Ein Heimatbuch in Bildern mit Anekdoten, Sagen, Geschichten und Erzählungen

https://www.grundschule-lahr-sulz.de/app/download/5792723418/Bei+uns+in+Sulz.pdf

Gedicht "d'Jakobsleiter" von Oswald Schaaf

*Dr Schakob het obends d'Laderne anzunde*

*dann het's dr Schakob widder heimwärts driwe*

Palatina: Heimatblatt des Pfälzer Anzeigers. 1871

https://books.google.de/books?id=dZFSAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=schakob&f=false

**Sonstiges:**

https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_VCwtAAAAYAAJ/bub_gb_VCwtAAAAYAAJ_djvu.txt

https://ewatlas.net/desfayes/285.php

http://maddingoesdownunder.blogspot.com/2007/

*bloeder Nudel- Schakob*

(Der Blogger kommt aus Bad Bergzabern, https://www.blogger.com/profile/11211932002853835115)